# Obtaining the stride of an Fortran Array

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I am currently modernizing some Fortran programs an I want to write a wrapper around an old style Fortran 77 routine with the signature

```
SUBROUTINE INITMATRIX( M , N , A , LDA) 
 INTEGER M, N, LDA 
 DOUBLE PRECISION A(LDA,*)
```

For this routine I wrote a wrapper taking a Fortran 90 style matrix as input

```
SUBROUTINE INITMATRIX_F90( A ) 
  DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT) :: A(:,:) 
  INTEGER :: M, N, LDA 
  M = SIZE(A,1) 
  N = SIZE(A,2) 
  LDA = SIZE(A,1) 
  CALL INITMATRIX(M, N, A, LDA)  
END SUBROUTINE
```

This works well unless I pass a slice into the routine. For example I have a 20 x 20 matrix and I only want to initialize the first 10 rows. Then I would call

```
DOUBLE PRECISION A(20,20) 
CALL INITMATRIX_F90(A(1:10,1:20))
```

which leads to an error since my wrapper gets the wrong leading dimension of the array. In the example I have `LDA=10` instead of `LDA = 20`. Is there a way to access the stride/extend of an array to recover the leading dimension? Regarding the ISO_Fortran_binding.h header file for interoperability with C the information is stored inside the array descriptor.

In order to visualize the problem, here is a MWE demostrating the issue.

```
PROGRAM MAIN
    INTERFACE
        SUBROUTINE INITMATRIX_F90(A)
            DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT) :: A(:,:)
        END SUBROUTINE

    END INTERFACE

    DOUBLE PRECISION :: A(20,20)
    A = 1.0D0

    CALL INITMATRIX_F90(A(1:10,1:20))

END PROGRAM MAIN

SUBROUTINE INITMATRIX_F90( A )
    USE ISO_C_BINDING
    IMPLICIT NONE


    DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT), POINTER :: A(:,:)
    INTEGER :: M, N, LDA
    TYPE(C_PTR) :: LOC1, LOC2
    INTEGER*16 :: LOCX1, LOCX2
    CHARACTER*32 :: TMP
    M = SIZE(A,1)
    N = SIZE(A,2)

    WRITE(TMP, *) C_LOC(A(1,1))
    READ(TMP, *) LOCX1
    WRITE(TMP, *) C_LOC(A(1,2))
    READ(TMP, *) LOCX2

    LDA = (LOCX2-LOCX1) / C_SIZEOF(A(1,1))

    WRITE(*,*) "M = ", M
    WRITE(*,*) "N = ", N
    WRITE(*,*) "LOC = ", LOCX1, LOCX2
    WRITE(*,*) "LDA(COMPUTED) = ", LDA

END SUBROUTINE
```

(I know that the pointer is missing in the interface, it is only there to make C_LOC work.)

The output then is

```
 M =           10
 N =           20
 LOC =  140721770410864 140721770411024
 LDA(COMPUTED) =           20
```

where obviously the leading dimension is computed correctly through a dirty hack. The internal structures, as used by the GNU Fortran compiler, or the ISO C <-> Fortran binding ( different to the ones used by GNU) include the information so how to access them from Fortran without dirty tricks.

Another MWE is the following wrapper around LAPACK's DLASET:

```
PROGRAM MAIN
    INTERFACE
        SUBROUTINE INITMATRIX2_F90(A)
            DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT) :: A(:,:)
        END SUBROUTINE

    END INTERFACE

    DOUBLE PRECISION :: A(20,20)
    A = 0.0D0

    CALL INITMATRIX2_F90(A(1:10,1:20))

    WRITE(*,*) A(1:20,1)

END PROGRAM MAIN

SUBROUTINE INITMATRIX2_F90( A )
    USE ISO_C_BINDING
    IMPLICIT NONE
    DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT) :: A(:,:)
    INTEGER :: M, N, LDA
    EXTERNAL DLASET
    M = SIZE(A,1)
    N = SIZE(A,2)
    CALL DLASET( "All", M, N, 1.0D0, 1.0D0, A(1,1) , M)
END SUBROUTINE
```

This gives 20 ones inside the first column of A instead of ten ones and ten zeros.

Comment: Why do have `LDA=SIZE(A,2)` when `LDA` is used as the first extent in `initmatrix`?

Comment: Also you do have an interface in scope when you call INITMATRIX_F90, don't you?

Comment: @francescalus Sorry, that was a typo. `LDA=SIZE(A,1)` would be correct. I fixed it. @Ian Bush The interface is in the scope.

Comment: So then `lda=10` _is_ correct, because that's the extent of the array that is being passed to `initmatrix`.  I think I'm not understanding your problem, so could you provide examples of input/output that you believe to be problematic?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm now completely lost, but I'll try.  Feel free to ignore me if I'm not helping.  In `initmatrix` any modifications you make to the dummy array `A` will be reflected in the actual argument `A` in `initmatrix_f90` and the ultimate argument the array slice `A(1:10,1:20)` of the main program.  `initmatrix_f90`'s array `A` isn't contiguous, explaining your "computed" LDA in that subroutine matching the slicing.  That `LDA` is entirely irrelevant when it comes to `initmatrix`'s array argument (which is contiguous).  What problems do you experience using the wrapper and the slice?

Comment: Out of interest, does your second example work as you expect if you use `A` as the argument to `dlaset` rather than `A(1,1)`?

Comment: The second example shows the wrong result which appears due to the fact, that I cannot access the extent or the leading dimension properly.  The expected result of the second example would be that the upper 10 rows of A are filled with ones and the lower 10 rows stay zero.

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu I am getting the correct `LDA` in your second case by subtracting the addresses. It is easier to just use `LOC` though. Did you actually print the value? I am getting 20 as expected.

Comment: And BTW, as I already mentioned, you are not supposed to use POINTER like this. My gfortran clearly complains. First, it must also be pointer in the interface. Second, the array you pass must also be a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that your modernizing effort would lead into a complete obfuscation. If you do have to call your `INITMATRIX` with something that is a slice, do not use your F90wrapper, you will not gain anything. Certainly not by what you plan, that would be illegal.

What will happen in

```
DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT) :: A(:,:) 

CALL INITMATRIX(M, N, A, LDA)
```

when A is not contiguous is that the compiler will make a copy of `A` and pass the copy. So trying to use the descriptor of the original array will be useless. Even if it did work, the code you would end up with would be worse than the original.

I recommend either modernizing the `INITMATRIX` itself, or just calling it directly the way you are calling it so far.

---

There are other options, like **passing only the first elements and then the stride information** (that is commonly done in MPI with subarray datatypes) but I would not recommend it. The original seems better.

```
CALL INITMATRIX(M, N, A(1,1), LDA)
```

If you actually do this in `INITMATRIX_F90`,you should it put into the first `INITMATRIX_F90` example to make it clear).

What you do in your new example with getting a difference of the address of the first elements of each column, that is in fact sometimes run. You can do it, it should work. It is easier if you either 1. use the common extensions `LOC` (and optionally `SIZEOF`), or 2. use `transfer()` to get the integer value, instead of the I/O routines. Note that an 8-byte integer is enough and best is to use `INTEGER(C_INTPTR_T)` (or ptrdiff).

---

Consider your MWE after I fixed the offending `POINTER` and removed the unnecessary bits:

```
PROGRAM MAIN
    INTERFACE
        SUBROUTINE INITMATRIX_F90(A)
            DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT) :: A(:,:)
        END SUBROUTINE
    END INTERFACE

    DOUBLE PRECISION :: A(20,20)
    A = 1.0D0
    print *,"loc in main",loc(A(1,1))
    CALL INITMATRIX_F90(A(1:10,1:10))
END PROGRAM MAIN

SUBROUTINE INITMATRIX_F90( A )
    IMPLICIT NONE
    DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT) :: A(:,:)

    print *,"LOC in INITMATRIX_F90:",loc(A(1,1))
    call external(A)
END SUBROUTINE

subroutine external(A)
  double precision :: A(*)
  print *,"LOC in external:", loc(A(1))
end subroutine
```

the output:

```
> ./a.out 
 loc in main      140721998532864
 LOC in INITMATRIX_F90:      140721998532864
 LOC in external:             37291664
```

As you can see, the compiler **made a copy** when passing `A` to the external procedure.

Comment: Not sure I get this - he/she's not trying to to use the descriptor of the original array if I read it correctly, but the descriptor of the sliced arracy as that is what is passed to initmatrix_f90, and if that's done correctly it should be OK, isn't it? Also (pedant mode) the compiler is not required to make a copy.

Comment: @IanBush It is not required but it will have very hard time to do anything else so it *will* do it (I didn't write it has to). Using the descriptor of the original or the argument of `INITMATRIX_F90` will have the same consequences in this regard, by original I mean before passing to `INITMATRIX`. In the end outside and inside of `NITMATRIX_F90` they describe the same original piece of memory (or a part of it). The point is that neither of these will describe the data that `INITMATRIX` will see.

Comment: The `INITMATRIX` function was only an example here. The code is modernized step by step but many interfaces to LAPACK/BLAS like packages exists and these external code cannot be rewritten. That's why we need this type of wrappers. We can guarantee that we only have slices that do not require a copy of the data. Due to the size of the data sets this is even not possible.

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu If you have such slices, then LDA should not change, otherwise you cannot guarantee that. In that case You can keep what you have. If not, please show an example of such a slice. The example in your question is not of such kind.

Comment: @Vladimir The constant leading dimension is guaranteed by our algorithms. But we need to access it. Our slices only cut of continuous parts inside a matrix column such that we do not skip every second row or similar things. DO the slices are all of the style mentioned in the example.  Our main goal is to get rid of the old longish Fortran 77 subroutine calls where ever it is possible.

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu The example you show does NOT guarantee that there will be no copy because it is NOT contiguous. That is because it does not span the whole column - the first index. That is why I ask you to either 1. provide an actual example that does guarantee that or 2. re-check what you actually have. Because my main point is: you can only guarantee that if you pass complete matrix columns. And if you do that you DO have the access to the LDA, it is just the same as `SIZE(A,1)`.

Comment: @Vladimir As mentioned before, we have the accesses like the one in the example. So continuous inside a column but not across them and thus the leading dimension is not `SIZE(A,1)`. We do not have slices where a copy is required and the compiler complains nowhere, that a (temporary) copy is made.

Comment: @VladimirF I modified the example for better illustration. Keeping track of memory addresses fortran creates only a copy is there is now other way to express it. That the stuff I recognized over the last decade. Lets consider the case of the example that we a contigous inside a column but not across them, then either the compiler make a copy of the sliced block -> LDA == size(A,1) or is passes the modified array descriptor ( and that's what happen mostly in our code) then the leading dimension LDA .ne. SIZE(A,2) and there lies the problem.

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu Please see the edit. And check the actual addresses. The compiler DOES make the copy. There is no other way. If there is other way, you have to explain it, because I (and clearly also the compiler) can't see any.

Comment: I check the address of A(1,1) using gdb before entering INITMATRIX and inside and it gave the the same result. To there is no copy.

Comment: @VladimirF I checked your MWE and yes in your case there is a copy. But from my experience with the IBM compilers I knew that calling external functions, that contain old style fortran code is dangerous, if one calls it like `CALL external(A)`. But calling `CALL external(A(1,1))` is does not lead to problems and the address stays the same, and then I need the leading dimension to work properly on A in the external routine.

Comment: Ok then there was a small missunderstanding. But after some discussion, it should now be clear where the problem ist. Using the same descriptor through all the function calls and accessing the leading dimension WITHOUT hacks.  `LDA = (LOC(A(1,2)) - LOC(A(1,1)))/SIZEOF(A(1,1))` I count as hack.

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu It is a hack, but it is what is normally done. I do not see anything better. Certainly not digging into descriptors.

Comment: From C we digg into the descriptors, but since function like SIZE and SHAPE are provides, I would be natural to have a STRIDE function as numpy provides when interfacing C <-> numpuy. But then I have to live with the hack.